# What is the purpose of RocksDBStore with Serdes.Bytes() and Serdes.ByteArray()?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

`RocksDBStore<K,V>` stores keys and values as `byte[]` on disk. It converts to/from `K` and `V` typed objects using `Serdes` provided while constructing the object of `RocksDBStore<K,V>`.

Given this, please help me understand the purpose of the following code in `RocksDbKeyValueBytesStoreSupplier`:

```
return new RocksDBStore<>(name,
                          Serdes.Bytes(),
                          Serdes.ByteArray());
```

Providing `Serdes.Bytes()` and `Serdes.ByteArray()` looks redundant.

`RocksDbKeyValueBytesStoreSupplier` is introduced in [KAFKA-5650](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-5650) (Kafka Streams 1.0.0) as part of [KIP-182: Reduce Streams DSL overloads and allow easier use of custom storage engines](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-182%3A+Reduce+Streams+DSL+overloads+and+allow+easier+use+of+custom+storage+engines).

In KIP-182, there is the following sentence :

> The new Interface BytesStoreSupplier supersedes the existing StateStoreSupplier (which will remain untouched). This so we can provide a convenient way for users creating custom state stores to wrap them with caching/logging etc if they chose. In order to do this **we need to force** the inner most store, i.e, the custom store, to be a store of type `<Bytes, byte[]>`.

Please help me understand why we need to force custom stores to be of type `<Bytes, byte[]>`?

Another place ([KAFKA-5749](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-5749)) where I found similar sentence:

> In order to support bytes store we need to create a MeteredSessionStore and ChangeloggingSessionStore. We then need to refactor the current SessionStore implementations to use this. All inner stores should by of type < Bytes, byte[] >

Why?

Answer (score 2):

Your observation is correct -- the PR implementing KIP-182 did miss to remove the Serdes from RocksDBStore that are not required anymore. This was fixed in 1.1 release already.